# How to add grid panel to the last node of tree-grid in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridview, extjs4.2, treepanel

Can anybody suggest an approach to add grid panel to the last node/children of treepanel. I want to append gridpanel dynamically, for reference i am attaching a link.
[Jsfiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5o9)

I also require to hide the gridpanel in collapse of the treepanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to remember your grid somewhere in your node component and then hide it on `itemcollapse` event.
Quick example based on your code https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lnc

Comment: But if you try to expand same node it is not getting load

Comment: I didn't make a perfect-working example, i just wanted to show you idea

Comment: is there a way to determine when are we at the very last node? in your example you are using depth, but it is not necessery to be true